# How to search for a string across all the sheets faster in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am tryng the search for a string across all sheets, the code below gets a string from each row in a column in one sheet and finds in another worksheet and then gets the formating of the corresponding cell for month.

The issue here is that it is very slow. How can I do this faster? is there a better way?

```
Sub colorstatus()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Range("H1").Activate
Dim c As Range

'//loop it
For Each c In Range(Range("H2"), Range("H2").End(xlDown))
    est1 = Split(c, "_")(0) & "_" & Split(c, "_")(1)


ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet
 Dim est As Range
 Dim strName As String
 Dim status As Range
 
 For Each ws1 In Worksheets
  Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
  Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Next
 
 On Error Resume Next
 strName = est1
 For Each ws In Worksheets
 With ws.UsedRange
 Set est = .Find(What:="*" & strName & "*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
 If Not est Is Nothing Then
 ws.Activate
 GoTo 0
 End If
 End With
 Next ws
0

est.Activate
Set status = Cells.Find(What:="*May*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False)
    

Range(Split(status.Address, "$")(1) & est.row).Copy


ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
c.Offset(0, 11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using the macro recorder and see what it comes with when you ctrl+f and set to all worksheets. A large chunk of my VBA knowledge has been built off of a recorded macro, analysing the results and then going from there. Not at windows machine right now, but its always a good starting point.

Comment: This is what comes up ther is no option in vba for searching by worksheet makes no sence                                                          
 `Cells.Find(What:="*May*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate`

Comment: Does that string appear more then once per each sheet? Can you reduce the range to be searched? I mean, if you know that it should be found only in columns A:F, for instance... What kind of string is in discussion? The string is the `Whole` cell value, or only part of it? Please, post such a string sample.

Comment: @FaneDuru string sample is "dog_390" or "my dog_394". its always at the beginning of the text in the cell and looks like it will always be found in column "A". in the first sheet I extract dog_390 from a bigger string

Comment: You answer partially... Does it appear only once per sheet? And I can only deduce that it is part of the cell value, not the whole value. Is my understanding correct. If yes, your code can be made to not waste time searching in all the sheet range.

Comment: yes the string will only appear once in the whole workbook, and I am searching part of the cell values

Comment: And could your code find `What:="*May*"` on the row in discussion?

Comment: "May" is a header. looks like its always in row 8

Comment: I cannot understand from your question/code, what is to be done after finding the string, supposing that the cell containing `May` will be found...

Comment: @FaneDuru Basically I get the row of the first range and column of the 2nd range to get the range corresponding to both. ie I want the month but month is not always in the same column so dont know where it is

Comment: You "want the month" but what is to be done after you find it...?

Comment: i am just finding the column the month cell is in so I know what cell to copy. the row comes from the first range. is that not clear?

Comment: It is and it was clear **how to find the cell**, but nothing clear about what is to be done with the cell in discussion. Please, check my answer code. It retrieves in 'Immediate Window' the cell value, cell address, or "No match found" for each worksheet...

Comment: Can you explain in which format that `May` exists? Is it a simple word, or a date? If a date, can you write here how it looks (not formatted). I have big doubt that a partial string from a formatted date can be retrieved by `Find` function...

Comment: Since you do  not say anything (about date format) I adapted the code to search the month number (on the first row). So, instead of 'May' you will use `5`. Try the updated code, please. Do not forget to refresh the page (this one).

Comment: it's just the word "may", it is not date format. all that is done with the cell it that it is copies and the formatting is pasted. in this case I am actually pasting the color of the cell

Comment: Then, try my updated code. I can see you do not try anything... At least you do not send any feedback to people posting answers...

Comment: I kinda had issues with the codes provided and wasnt sure how to implement. mine worked fine. it looks like the reason it was taking long was mainly bc I ran the "unhide" every time I looped through each cell but it was only necessary the first time

Answer (score 0):

The below code loop all sheets and generate a message box with all sheets names have the value in. You can modify and try:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim strSearch As String, strResults As String
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    strSearch = "Test"
    strResults = ""
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        With ws
        
            Set rngFound = .Cells.Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            
            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            
                If strResults = "" Then
                    strResults = "Searching value, " & strSearch & ", appears in " & ws.Name
                Else
                    strResults = strResults & ", " & ws.Name
                End If
                
            End If
            
        End With
        
    Next ws
    
    If strResults <> "" Then
        MsgBox strResults & "."
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will end either a message with the address for the cell which the word was found, or a message telling you that it didn't found the word:

```
Option Explicit
Sub colorstatus()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim TheWord As String: TheWord = "dog_390"
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Set cell = ws.Range("A:A").Find(TheWord, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not cell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Word " & TheWord & "found in cell: " & cell.Address & " in worksheet: " & ws.Name
            End
        End If
    Next ws
    MsgBox "Word " & TheWord & " was not found on this workbook."
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub colorstatus()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, celFound As Range, strWord As String
    Dim status As Range
    
     strWord = "dog_390"
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Set celFound = sh.Range("A:A").Find(strWord, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not celFound Is Nothing Then
            Set status = sh.Rows(1).Find(What:="May", After:=sh.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart)
            If Not status Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print sh.Name, sh.cells(celFound.Row, status.Column).Interior.Color, sh.cells(celFound.Row, status.Column).Address
                'do whatever you need with the found cell...
                '....
            Else
                Debug.Print sh.Name, "No month found"
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print sh.Name, "No match found"
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```